# Rails: How to define one model's submodel in a third model's controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, associations

I have three models: Thing, Category, and Rating. Thing and Category each have_many of each other :through :category_things, but only Category has_many Ratings, :through :category_ratings. I want to put @thing.categories.ratings in my Thing view, but I can't figure out how to define it in my Things controller. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    @category = Category.all
    @thing.categories.build
    @category_thing = CategoryThing.all
    @category_rating = CategoryRating.all
    @rating = Rating.all
    @thing.categories.ratings.build
  end
end
```

But when I go to my Thing/show view, I get the following error:

```
undefined method 'ratings' for #<ActiveRedord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Category:0xb34c6d24>
```

Thing Model:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_things
  has_many :categories, :through => :category_things
  attr_accessor :category_names
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "30x30!" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Category Model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_ratings
  has_many :ratings, :through => :category_ratings
  has_many :category_things
  has_many :things, :through => :category_things
end
```

CategoryThing Model:

```
class CategoryThing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :thing
end
```

Rating Model:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_ratings
  has_many :categories, :through => :category_ratings
  has_many :thing_ratings
  has_many :things, :through => :thing_ratings
  has_many :up_votes
  has_many :down_votes
end
```

CategoryRating Model:

```
class CategoryRating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :rating
end
```

I'm using Rails 4.0.10.

Comment: That's right. One object has `ratings`, a collection of such objects doesn't. Consider looking into "eager loading". This is not enough for an answer, it's rather a direction for a search.

Comment: I researched eager loading, but I'm not sure how that could lead to a solution to my problem.

Comment: show us your models with their associations please.

Comment: If ratings should be grouped by categories they are in, then you could fetch ratings **into** corresponding groups and output them for each category in a nested loop. If not... then things get complicated.

Comment: @Anthony I added them above.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html tells me that you can put a hash into .include for deeper eager loading.

You could do (not tested, you might need to play around with this):

```
@thing = Thing.include({categories: :ratings}).find(params[:id])
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

'@thing.categories' is an association proxy representing a collection of objects. 
The error message is telling you that there is no  'ratings' method on the **collection** of categories.  Only an **instance** of category can have **ratings** associated with it. You need to save off the instance of category created buy the **@thing.categories.build** and then get your ratings from that.  Also I see a few naming issues in your view action that I'd change in order to make the intention clearer.

Try this

```
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  @categories = Category.all  # All possible categories?
  @category = @thing.categories.build  # create a new category that belongs to this instance of 'thing'
  @category_things = CategoryThing.all # All possible category_things?
  @category_ratings = CategoryRating.all # All possible category_ratings?
  @rating = Rating.all ## All possible ratings?
```

You would have to modify your show view to reflect these changes. I don't know what is in your show view but I assume since you are "building" the category through thing associations you must have a form (that is using nested attributes) on the page which when submitted to the thing controller will actually create the category. If this is not the case then you should update your question with the code from the show view and clarify what you are trying to achieve.